# What is the difference between 見る and 見える?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, potential-form

I've been coming across this weird verb conjugation that seems to happen in some verbs, where you replace る with える, e.g. 見る → 見える。

Is this a different verb form, how does it change the meaning of the verb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 見える【みえる】／聞こえる【きこえる】 and 見られる【みられる】／聞ける【きける】?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/what-is-the-difference-between-%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%bf%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-%e8%81%9e%e3%81%93%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%8d%e3%81%93%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-and-%e8%a6%8b%e3%82%89%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%bf%e3%82%89%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b-%e8%81%9e%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%8d%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b)

Comment: 見る to look; 見える to see

Comment: Same thing with 聞く to listen; 聞こえる to hear. First one has active effort, second one is more passive, I guess. (The English approximations aren't really that good.)

Comment: @broccoliforest I don't think that's a duplicate; it focusses on the potential form only.

Comment: 見る is "watch", 見える is "can see".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

見る and 見える are separate verbs in the present Japanese language.

You know, 見る is to look at.

見える has a couple of meanings; they also apply to other verbs like 聞こえる, 思える, etc.

1. possibility.

   > ここから東京スカイツリーが見える。
   >
   > We can see the Tokyo Sky Tree here.
2. occurring unintentionally.

   > ちょっと見えただけなんだ。君のスカートの中を見ようとしたわけじゃないよ。
   >
   > It merely jumped into my sight; I was never trying to see what's in your skirt.
3. to seem.

   > 彼はこの時間をとても楽しんでいるように見える。
   >
   > He seems to be having a really good time.