# "I see you" Translation

Tags: grammar

> 私があなたを見る。

vs.

> あなたが見えてます。

Which sentence is closer to "I see you"?
In the first, I tried using が to mark 私 as the doer of the verb. Then I used を to mark the direct object of the verb. The second is what Google Translate gave which is totally different than how I would have gone about it.

Also, what would the normal way to say "I see you" be?

Comment: Do you know that みえる is a potential for for みる?

Comment: Just so we are clear, you are not talking about the slang meaning of "I see you": "good job!" "You are awesome!", are you?

Comment: @EddieKal Weird. Never heard of that slang as a UK person. Putting aside that interpretation 'I see you' is a weird thing to say on its own anyway. It brings to mind hide and seek or peekaboo. Needs more context.

Comment: @user3856370 Perhaps on a Zoom meeting it wouldn't be quite so weird, but in a Zoom meeting, I think I'd just say みえる.  But I too here on the other side of the pond am not familiar with this *slang*.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between 見る and 見える?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39242/43676)

Comment: @user3856370 I can say that in the US, "I see you" is indeed slang to show that you are impressed with someone. I agree that there is ambiguity here, and I think the slang meaning would be totally lost on anyone reading this in Japanese.

Comment: I don't think the Hobbits speak Japanese, Lord Sauron...  ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are similar, but carry slightly different meanings.

I think the most pressing thing to take note of is the difference between 見る and 見える. For a deeper understanding, I suggest checking out [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/what-is-the-difference-between-%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%bf%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-%e8%81%9e%e3%81%93%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%8d%e3%81%93%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-and-%e8%a6%8b%e3%82%89%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%bf%e3%82%89%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b-%e8%81%9e%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%8d%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b) and [this thread.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39242/what-is-the-difference-between-%e8%a6%8b%e3%82%8b-and-%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b) But, for now, I will focus on the most likely application of the word:

見る: to look. (the action of looking)

見える: to be visible. (the action of having the ability to be looked at)

> 私があなたを見る

If we break this down literally, it would be something like "I am look(ing) at you."

> あなたが見えてます。

And if we broke this one down literally, it would be "You are visible"/"You are seen."

Thusly, if you wanted not to say "I am look(ing) at you" but instead, "I can see you" (lit: You are visible to me) it would be:

> 私にはあなたが見えてます。