# Combination of causative-passive and intransive verb with a direct object?

Tags: parsing, passive-voice, potential-form, causation

I am struggling to understand this sentence’s structure:

> 宿題を時間内に終わらせられなかった。

I think I get the idea of causative-passive as in “I was being made to finish the homework”. However, I noticed that we have the intransitive verb 終わる and not the transitive 終える. But we also have a direct object 宿題. Unless I am the object in this case? I am really confused.

Would this sentence translate to:

**I couldn’t be made to finish the homework in time.**

Or to:
**I couldn’t be made to be finished with the homework in time.**

Also, I can’t think of a way not to add the ‘potential form’ in English. Is there a potential form hidden there somewhere in Japanese?

Comment: also relevant: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/when-is-%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B-used-as-a-transitive-verb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(ら)れる has both a potential meaning and a passive meaning (along with [other two less common meanings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43898/5010)). For example, 食べられる means both "to be able to eat" and "to be eaten". In your sentence, れる has a potential meaning.

- 終わる: (simple intransitive verb) "to end"
- 終わら**せる**: [causative] "to make something end" (i.e., "to finish something")
- 終わらせら**れる**: [causative-**potential**] "can make something end"
- 終わらせられ**ない**: [negative-causative-potential] "cannot make something end"
- 終わらせられなかっ**た**: [past-negative-causative-potential] "could not make something end"

> 宿題を時間内に終わらせられなかった。
>   I could not finish my homework in time.

You can say the same thing using the transitive verb 終える:

> 宿題を時間内に終えられなかった。
>   I could not finish my homework in time.

Related: [Is there a reason why the passive and the potential form are identical (at least for える/いる verbs)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60050/5010)