何が見えますか vs 何が見られますか
From a language learning app, it translates between what can you see? and 何が見えますか?
However, according to online Japanese dictionaries, I see (pun unintended) that:

見る - to see/watch something
見える - to be seen

In that case, shouldn't it be that:

何が見られますか? - what can you see?
何が見えられますか? - what can be seen?
何が見えますか? - what is to be seen?


See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43881 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5287. Both 見える and 見られる are inherently passive/potential. Old Japanese had 2 relevant suffixes: spontaneous/passive/potential suffix -aye- (~ -raye-), spontaneous/passive suffix -are- (-rare- variant appeared in Middle Japanese; potential function not attested in Old Japanese). So etymologically 見える and 聞こえる are forms of 見る and 聞く with suffix -aye-. This suffix mostly died out, but survived in few words (also e.g. あらゆる, 言わゆる).

見られる is always explicitly about one's ability, opportunity, or permission to see something. This form assumes the subject wants to see it. In contrast, 見える can neutrally describe the visibility of something, without implying desire. This difference is often unimportant, but is significant in some cases.

この部屋からは富士山が見えます and この部屋からは富士山が見られます are interchangeable, with almost no difference, since being able to see Mt. Fuji is considered desirable.
何が見えますか is a neutral and natural question about what is visible to the listener right now. 何が見られますか sounds more like "What are we able/allowed to see?" or "What is available to see?"
隣の人のスマホ画面が見えた usually means you accidentally saw the smartphone screen of the person next to you. If 見られた is used instead, it suggests you intentionally tried to peek at it.

Note that 見られる is commonly shortened to 見れる in colloquial Japanese (although this should be avoided in formal Japanese). 見えられますか is always grammatically incorrect.

Thanks! Your second point illustrates very well what I understand as well. My interpretation of the "what can you see?" in the original post is more of "what are you able to see?" rather than "what is visible to you?" hence I thought "何が見られますか?" sounds a closer translation. But I agree that in many cases, the difference is minute.

As for "見えられますか is always grammatically incorrect". Hmm, that I don't fully understand. I thought that, 見る and 見える are the "root form" of two different verbs, meaning respectively "to see (something)" (transitive) and "to be seen" (intransitive). And then, each one has its own "can"/"potential" (られ) form which are, respectively, "見られます" and "見えられます" (Reference: https://jlearn.net/dictionary/%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B and https://jlearn.net/dictionary/%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)

@PieFaced 見える already has a potential sense ("is visible" or "can see"), so it doesn't make sense to add another potential suffix. Similarly, できる is a verb that describes potential, so it never conjugates to the potential form.
