# Why would you use 見えます instead of 見ます?

Tags: conjugations, て-form, potential-form

In the song イドラサーカス sung by 鏡音{かがみね}リン, there is the line, 「青{あお}い空{そら}が汚{よご}れて見{み}えますか？」I translated it using て as the present continuous. "Can you see the blue sky becoming dirty?"
Is my translation right and, if so, why would you say 見{み}えます? Wouldn't you conjugate 見{み}ます using ます form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb you are seeing is [見える](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B), which means either "to be visible" or "to seem/appear/look". `te-form + 見える` usually means the latter, "to appear to (have) ～" or "to appear as if ～".

> - 彼が若返って見える。
>     He looks as if he has gotten younger.
> - まるで時間が止まって見える。
>     It appears as if the time stopped.
> - 青い空が汚れて見えますか？
>     Does the blue sky appear to be dirty (to you)?

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing [見る](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B) (to see) with [見える](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B) (able to see / to be seen). Similarly there is 聞く (to hear) and 聞こえる (to be able to hear / to be heard).

I have a hard time describing the differences, but luckily there [is another answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/what-is-the-difference-between-%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E8%81%9E%E3%81%93%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%93%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-and-%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%BF%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-%E8%81%9E%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B).